# Install marvel plugin for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch-marvel

I have downloaded the version 1.1.0 of elasticsearch, and it's running well. I would like to install the marvel plugin, so I run the following command from the elasticsearch home directory (exactly like told in the official tutorial at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/marvel/current/#_simple_install):

```
bin\plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

But I get the following error:

```
-> Installing elasticsearch/marvel/latest...
Trying http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/marvel/marvel-latest.zip.
..
Trying http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=elasticsearch/marvel/lates
t/marvel-latest.zip...
Trying https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/elas
ticsearch/marvel/latest/marvel-latest.zip...
Trying https://github.com/elasticsearch/marvel/archive/vlatest.zip...
Trying https://github.com/elasticsearch/marvel/archive/master.zip...
Failed to install elasticsearch/marvel/latest, reason: failed to download out of
 all possible locations..., use -verbose to get detailed information
```

And this is what I get when I use -verbose:

```
-> Installing elasticsearch/marvel/latest...
Trying http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/marvel/marvel-latest.zip.
..
Failed: UnknownHostException[download.elasticsearch.org]
Trying http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=elasticsearch/marvel/lates
t/marvel-latest.zip...
Failed: UnknownHostException[search.maven.org]
Trying https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/elas
ticsearch/marvel/latest/marvel-latest.zip...
Failed: UnknownHostException[oss.sonatype.org]
Trying https://github.com/elasticsearch/marvel/archive/vlatest.zip...
Failed: UnknownHostException[github.com]
Trying https://github.com/elasticsearch/marvel/archive/master.zip...
Failed: UnknownHostException[github.com]
Failed to install elasticsearch/marvel/latest, reason: failed to download out of
 all possible locations..., use -verbose to get detailed information
```

Comment: I'm getting this same exact issue too. You would think that the [getting started guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_installing_elasticsearch.html) that we're both following would be accurate! :(

Comment: NOTE: This post is from 2014. The plugin system in Elasticsearch has changed since late 2015 with the release of Elasticsearch 2.0. Please look for a more recent version or ask a new one (and have any "dupe" pointed out)!

Comment: Seriously - I'm the 25,000th viewer of this page? Maybe elastic should improve their plugin's _search_ capabilities

Answer (score 30):

You could try to go to the address http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/marvel/marvel-latest.zip with your web browser. If you can download the marvel-latest.zip that way then you can manually create plugins directory under elasticsearch directory and unzip the marvel-latest.zip file in the plugins directory, i.e. the zip contents should go to
plugins\marvel directory under ElasticSearch home directory.

Be sure to rename the unzipped directory from marvel-latest to marvel, so that address

```
http://any-server-in-cluster:9200/_plugin/marvel/
```

suggested in the tutorial works.

I had somewhat similar problem as you with the ElasticSearch version 1.1.1. The

```
bin\plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

command gave FileNotFound errors though with the web browser I was able to download the plugin and get it work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did the manuel installation and it worked.

Comment: I'm getting unknown plugin for both the license and marvel. I'm using powershell admin. I'm in the bin folder of elastic search using this command, `./elasticsearch-plugin.bat install elasticsearch\license\latest`.

Comment: Is marvel replaced by x-pack perhaps? Cause I'm able to install x-pack with the command above.

Answer (score 26):

This works for Elasticsearch 2.0+ and Kibana 4.2+
according to https://www.elastic.co/downloads/marvel

**Step 1**: Install Marvel into Elasticsearch:

`/path/to/elasticsearch/bin/./plugin install license`

`/path/to/elasticsearch/bin/./plugin install marvel-agent`

---

**Step 2**: Install Marvel into Kibana

`/path/to/kibana/bin/./kibana plugin --install elasticsearch/marvel/latest`

---

**Step 3**: Start Elasticsearch and Kibana

`/path/to/elasticsearch/bin/./elasticsearch`

`/path/to/kibana/bin/./kibana`

---

**Step 4**: Navigate to http://localhost:5601/app/marvel

---

**Step 5**: For installing Sense into Kibana:

`/path/to/kibana/bin/./kibana plugin --install elastic/sense`

Answer (score 6):

This works for me :

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
./plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

output :

```
-> Installing elasticsearch/marvel/latest...
Trying http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/marvel/marvel-latest.zip...
Downloading ........................................DONE
Installed elasticsearch/marvel/latest into /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/marvel
```

**EDIT: License install**

```
./plugin -i elasticsearch/license/latest
```

Answer (score 3):

Run your CMD as administrator and the latest marvel download will start.

Comment: Actually, I found this was the exact answer to the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate the steps in detail? I am getting error `'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 2):

You can get more Elasticsearch plugins accessing here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html

Plugins installed to use with Elasticsearch are saved in the folder '../usr/share/elasticsearch' (by default).

To install Marvel plugin you can do:

```
cd ../usr/share/elasticsearch
bin/plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

Acessible in: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/_installation.html

Comment: If you want install another plugins you do the same, like:
   
    cd ../usr/share/elasticsearch
    bin/plugin -i plugin-name

Answer (score 1):

Try running with proxy if you are behind one.
Go to your elasticsearch installation path.

In my case > /usr/share/elasticsearch

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch

bin/plugin -DproxyPort=<porxyPort> -DproxyHost=<proxyHostDNSorIP> install license

bin/plugin -DproxyPort=<porxyPort> -DproxyHost=<proxyHostDNSorIP> install shield
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing manually. following are the steps-

1. download it from here-https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/marvel/marvel-latest.zip
2. Place it into your server.
3. cd Path/To/elasticsearch-1.x.x
4. bin/plugin -i marvel -u file:///Path/where/you/placed/marvel-latest.zip
5. Restart your elastic search.
6. Go to any mordern browser and write  http://any-server-in-cluster:9200/_plugin/marvel/