# Error Marvel plugin Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I'm not able to access marvel in my browser.

http://localhost:9200/_plugins/marvel/ returns

```
{"error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No feature for name [marvel]]","status": 400}
```

I have installed elastic search 1.7.1  and its up and running running at http://localhost:9200/

I'm running on a window 2008R2 server with chrome and java 1.7.0_79

I did (and tried) the following things:

- I installed the marvel plugin marvel (marvel-latest.zip).   The
  folder marvel folder is created in the plugins folder
- The log shows the plugin is started  ([INFO ][plugins        ]
  *[MY_01_dev] loaded [marvel], sites [marvel])*
- tried giving in teh path to the index page manually (http://localhost:9200/_plugins/marvel/_site/kibana/index.html#/dashboard)
- Changed the config with: marvel.agent.exporter.es.hosts: localhost:9200

No luck so far, all commands with cURL seems to work, but as much as I'm fond of command lines, my colleagues aren't, so i realy would like to get the plugin up and running

Answer (score 1):

The url is not with `_plugins`, but with `_plugin` (singular):

http://localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel/kibana/index.html#/dashboard/file/marvel.overview.json

Comment: Arrrggg... that fixes it!

Answer (score -1):

Marvel and sense plugin should be installed to Kibana and then access it using marvel agent on elastic node.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732567/1013528

Comment: That answer is for Elastic 2.0+ question mentioned 1.7. Also, this question was already answered if you read the other comments