# elasticsearch marvel installation on windows

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, cmd, 64-bit, elasticsearch-marvel

I have downloaded `elasticsearch2.0` and it runs with no problems. I want to add marvel plugin and tried all instruction on the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/installing-marvel.html and [Install marvel plugin for Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604868/install-marvel-plugin-for-elasticsearch) - it didn't help.

I am trying to install the plugin on `windows8.1 64bit`. When I typed

```
bin/plugin install elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

from elasticsearch directory it says:

> bin is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

when I typed

```
plugin install elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

from elasticsearch/bin directory it says:

> Failed to install elasticsearch/marvel/latest, reason: failed to download out of
>    all possible locations..., use -verbose to get detailed information

I also tried manual installation. I downloaded latest marvel (2.0) and put in `elasticsearch/plugin/marvel` directory then run

`plugin install marvel -u marvelfilepath`

It gives error

> unrecognized option -u "-i , -u " commands are not recognized from cmd.

How can I install marvel plugin. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try,copying extracted marvel binaries folder in ES_HOME/plugins directory and restart your node.Restarting the node will automatically pickup plugins available in ES_HOME/plugins directory.