# How to execute Elasticsearch query in Marvel 2.0 plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, sense, elasticsearch-marvel

After I upgraded to the latest Marvel plugin, I don't know how to find the Sense dashboard where I can execute query and see the formatted result.  I've visited Marvel documentation but no idea where to find the dashboard.

Comment: Have you installed Kibana? That's the only way I know how to get to it

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33732567/2308683

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Turns out I need to install Sense as a separate plugin.  After issuing `bin/kibana plugin --install elastic/sense` and restarting Kibana, I now have access to Sense again.

Comment: Welcome. I guess I should've answered with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on ElasticSearch's page is a bit scattered, but this answer looks like what you need.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732567/2308683