# Does sense only work in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic 2.0 and I am trying to access sense from the following URL:

http://localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel/sense/index.html

I followed the instruction on installing sense from here:

[Install marvel plugin for Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604868/install-marvel-plugin-for-elasticsearch/33732567#33732567)

However I'm only able to access sense from within Kibana if I try to access it from elastic I get a blank page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sense has become a kibana app and so is Marvel 2.0. The URL you are trying will throw 404 error.

As you said the correct way to access is `http://localhost:5601/app/sense` considering default settings.

[More](https://www.elastic.co/blog/sense-2-0-0-beta1) on that

Comment: Many thanks, although what I find bizarre is if it only works in Kibana now, why do the instructions state to install it within Elastic and Kibana?

Comment: You need to install marvel in both ES and kibana because It has two components, one to collect metrics and other one to visualize those in kibana. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/introduction.html#_monitoring_with_marvel) on that.

Comment: Just to confirm I installed a fresh copy of ES and Kibana on a new box and I did not have to install sense in Elastic, only in Kibana and everything seems to work fine in sense, I can drop indexes and create indexes etc.

Comment: You are right. I was talking about Marvel, you need that on both, and sense in kibana only.