# Elasticsearch 6.3: Unknown Plugin Marvel-agent

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I have installed Elasticsearch 6.3 following the steps: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html#_installation_example_with_msi_windows_installer .

Now I would like to install Marvel-sense plugin for GUI interaction with my cluster. I am facing few issues in installing this plugin. I have just followed the steps mentiond in,

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/installing-marvel.html
2. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/installation.html

Command used:

```
F:\MJSpace\elasticsearch-6.3.2\bin>elasticsearch-plugin install marvel-agent
A tool for managing installed elasticsearch plugins

Commands
--------
list - Lists installed elasticsearch plugins
install - Install a plugin
remove - removes a plugin from Elasticsearch

Non-option arguments:
command

Option         Description
------         -----------
-h, --help     show help
-s, --silent   show minimal output
-v, --verbose  show verbose output
ERROR: Unknown plugin marvel-agent

F:\MJSpace\elasticsearch-6.3.2\bin>
```

Also I **could not find Marvel-sense in the available list of plugins**.

```
C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.3.2\bin>elasticsearch-plugin install -h

Install a plugin

The following official plugins may be installed by name:
  analysis-icu
  analysis-kuromoji
  analysis-phonetic
  analysis-smartcn
  analysis-stempel
  analysis-ukrainian
  discovery-azure-classic
  discovery-ec2
  discovery-file
  discovery-gce
  ingest-attachment
  ingest-geoip
  ingest-user-agent
  mapper-murmur3
  mapper-size
  repository-azure
  repository-gcs
  repository-hdfs
  repository-s3
  store-smb

Non-option arguments:
plugin id

Option             Description
------             -----------
-E <KeyValuePair>  Configure a setting
-b, --batch        Enable batch mode explicitly, automatic confirmation of
                     security permission
-h, --help         show help
-s, --silent       show minimal output
-v, --verbose      show verbose output

C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.3.2\bin>
```

I am trying this for past two days. Anyone who have been working with Elasticsearch, please point me where I am doing this wrong.

P.S: I have also referred one SO question: [Install marvel plugin for Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604868/install-marvel-plugin-for-elasticsearch) which is of different ES version and different case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install X-Pack

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/getting-started.html

> From version 5.0 onward, Marvel is part of X-Pack. For more information, see Monitoring Elasticsearch and Kibana in the X-Pack Reference.

Comment: it says like below 

bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
ERROR: this distribution of Elasticsearch contains X-Pack by default